# Make symbols global in already compiled object file

Tags: object-files, nm

Suppose I have an object file with no available source code that contains some non-exported symbols (marked by lowercase t's in the output of `nm`) that I would like to make visible. How can I do that? (Linux x86_64, and maybe OS X, too)